# Devexpress gridview focused to next row by enter

Tags: gridview, devexpress

Hi I'm using `devexpress`.

I have a gridview and I want to do that when i press enter then go down cell of my gridview cell.I hope I could explain . Thank you

Comment: I have a gridview with many columns. I would like to use the entery key in place of tab key for moving from one column to the next.  I could this with the KeyDown of other controls line

Answer (score 0):

raise `ProcessGridKey` GridControl Event :

```
   private void dgv_ProcessGridKey(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        GridControl grid = sender as GridControl;
        KeyPress(grid.MainView, e);
    }

    private void KeyPress(BaseView sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        var view = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
          e.Handled = true;
          dgv.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    view.CloseEditor();
                                     view.MoveNext();

                                }), null);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for wpf gridcontrol 14.1 and 15.1, use the GridControl_KeyDown/KeyUp events:

```
private void AnalyseResultGridControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                AnalyseResultGridControl.View.CloseEditor();
                AnalyseResultGridControl.View.MoveNextRow();
            }
        }
```